# How to mutate list of objects in lighthouse GraphQL

Tags: graphql, laravel-lighthouse

i have schema:

```
input CreateProduct {
    id_product: Int
    content: CreateContentHasMany
    manufacturer: CreateManufacturerHasOne
    codes: ProductCodesInput
}
type Mutation {
    createProduct(product: CreateProduct! @spread): Product @create
    createProducts(products: [CreateProduct!]): [Product]! @create
}
```

my query:

```
mutation {
    createProducts(
        products: [
            {
                content: {
                    create: [
                        {name: "some name"}
                    ]
                }
                codes: {
                    reference: "AAA666"
                }
            }
        ]
    ){
        id_product
    }
}
```

Create single product works,
but when i try to create list of products i have error:

`Array to string conversion`.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `@create` directive is only designed to create a single entry.
You can create a custom mutator to handle batch creation.

Create the custom mutator with the artisan command:
`php artisan lighthouse:mutation createProducts`

Due to the mutator having the same name as the mutator class, it will automatically be used.
If you create a it with a different name you may use the `@field`directive to resolve it.

```
input CreateProduct {
    id_product: Int
    content: CreateContentHasMany
    manufacturer: CreateManufacturerHasOne
    codes: ProductCodesInput
}
type Mutation {
    createProduct(product: CreateProduct! @spread): Product @create
    createProducts(products: [CreateProduct!]): [Product]!
}
```

This code is not tested, but just for inspiration! :)

```php
<?php

namespace App\GraphQL\Mutations;

class CreateProducts
{
    /**
     * @param  null  $_
     * @param  array<string, mixed>  $args
     */
    public function __invoke($_, array $args)
    {
        // unsafe batch insert. Take care of relations!
        return Product::insert($args['products']);

        // loop and create
        $products = [];
        foreach ($args['products'] as $productData) {
            // Create product. Take care of relations!
            Product::create($productData);
            // to
            $product = new Product();
            $product->fill($productData);
            // do whatever before saving. E.g. solve and set relations
            $product->save();
            $products[] = $product;
        }
        return $products;

    }
}
```